# OData v4 via Excel - The required attribute Relationship is missing

Tags: excel, asp.net-web-api, odata, linqpad, powerquery

I'm trying to test a new OData v4 web API I'm building with Excel and LinqPad but I'm getting the following error:

> The required attribute Relationship is missing

The API seems correctly built, but "Relationship" never turns up in metadata, no matter how I structure the model.

What's going on? I'm sensing that v3 and 4 are not compatible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PowerQuery does not yet support OData v4. You can harrass the development team here: :)

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/2169958f-9e2a-4fc2-a844-c0dce4c17a19/support-of-odata-v40?forum=powerquery

LinqPad's driver is clearly v3, but a search on linqpad.net reveals no mention of v4.

Comment: The OData team at MS haven't made this easy. It's almost impossible to make LINQPad support both V3 and V4. And if I target OData V4, it's not backwards compatible with V3.

Comment: Hey Joe. I'm a paying customer of LinqPad, very happy to have bought it. I'm sorry to hear of your woes with v4. I haven't touched OData for years and I'm wondering whether to also include v3 support in my service (apparently can run 3 and 4 side-by-side) since I'm getting the feeling the ink is still too wet on v4. Maybe post something on the LinqPad.net about where you stand with it?

Comment: If it makes you feel better, the Power Query team has the same problem :P. I understand why things are they way they are, but it does make life difficult for tools which need to support both v3 and v4.